# Is possible to create a Cordova plugin with Dart?

Tags: cordova, flutter, dart, interop

Is possible to create a Cordova plugin using Dart? Specifically Dart for mobile apps, the same that uses Flutter, but I don't need the UI part, just TCP, classes and so on. The idea is to use the Dart code that I already wrote in an existing Cordova app. I don't find any information about it. I think on to create a Flutter module and then use it in Android/iOS components, and then use these native components in a Cordova plugin, but I don't know if that is possible. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?